# JSON data deserialize using Regular Expressions

Tags: json, regex, abap

I'm facing issue while fetching keys and values from the data using regular expression if the JSON contains \ & ".

```
{
   "KeyOne":"Value One",
   "KeyTwo": "Value \\ two",
   "KeyThree": "Value \" Three",
   "KeyFour": "ValueFour\\"
}
```

It is sample data, from this I want to read the values are keys. How can I achieve with regular expressions.

Note: I'm deserializing this JSON data in the server side(SAP ABAP).

Comment: If you want to parse JSON, use JSON parser, not regular expressions. Regexps ar not the right tool to do it.

Comment: I'm not doing it in the UI , am doing at server side. It is in SAP ABAP.

Comment: Don't you have a JSON parser in ABAP?

Comment: @mrzasa, I modified my question. I need it in the ABAP. So, I can use RegEx only.

Comment: @mrzasa. Nope. I wrote one regex but it failed when \ came at the end value("ValueFour\\") it is working in all other case.

Comment: I'm pretty sure you can find a JSON parser for ABAP: https://www.google.com/search?q=abap+json+parser It's **always** a bad idea to try to parse JSON with regexes.

Comment: @mrzasa, I check this but it will also fail when \ came end of the value

Answer (score 2):

As @mrzasa and @joanis said in their comments: **Do not use RegEx to parse JSON!**

For small objects or when performance is not a concern, you can use `/ui2/cl_json`:

```
TYPES:
  BEGIN OF lty_foo_bar,
    KeyOne TYPE string,
    KeyTwo Type string,
    KeyThree TYPE string,
    KeyFour Type string,
  END OF lty_foo_bar.

DATA:
    lv_json_string TYPE string,
    ls_data TYPE lty_foo_bar.

 lv_json_string = |\{| &&
   |"KeyOne":"Value One",| &&
   |"KeyTwo": "Value \\\\ two", | &&
   |"KeyThree": "Value \\" Three", | &&
   |"KeyFour": "ValueFour\\\\" | &&
   |\}|.

/ui2/cl_json=>deserialize(
  EXPORTING
     json = lv_json_string
  CHANGING
     data = ls_data ).
```

`ls_data-KeyOne` contains `'Value One'` and so on.

For larger objects and/or better performance check `lxml` from [@phil soadys answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57897830/10009545) below. The correct handling of upper and lower case letters still causes headache in ABAP anyways.

Comment: /ui2/cl_json  is very slow on large JSON documents.

Answer (score 2):

On earlier releases less than 7.2 (from memory) you can use class `/ui2/cl_json`

if on 7.3 or later use  kernel IXML writer which support JSON.
It is orders of magnitude faster than /ui2/cl_json

you can use identity transformation approach where the source structure is known
and you can create that structure in abap or already has an abap equivalent defined. Otherwise just traverse the JSON document.
The example string was easily parsed

**EDIT: Add sample code**

```
REPORT zjsondemo.

CLASS lcl DEFINITION CREATE PUBLIC.

  PUBLIC SECTION.
    METHODS json_stru_known.
    METHODS json_stru_traverse.

ENDCLASS.

CLASS lcl IMPLEMENTATION.

  METHOD json_stru_known.
    DATA l_src_json TYPE string.
    DATA l_mara TYPE mara.

    WRITE: / 'DEMO 1 Known structure Identity transformation '.

    l_src_json = `{"MARA":{"MATNR":"012345678", "MATKL": "DUMMY" }}`.
    WRITE: / 'Conver to MARA -> ', l_src_json.

    CALL TRANSFORMATION id SOURCE XML l_src_json
          RESULT mara = l_mara.  "

    WRITE: / 'MARA -  MATNR', l_mara-matnr,
           / '        MATKL', l_mara-matkl.

TYPES:
  BEGIN OF lty_foo_bar,
    KeyOne TYPE string,
    KeyTwo Type string,
    KeyThree TYPE string,
    KeyFour Type string,
  END OF lty_foo_bar.

DATA:
    lv_json_string TYPE string,
    ls_data TYPE lty_foo_bar.
 " in this example we use upper case attribute names 
  "because we map to SAP target 
  " structure which has upper case names.   
  " if you need lowercase variables then you can not map straight to an
  " SAP type.  Then you need to use the traverse technique. See example 2
 lv_json_string = |\{| &&
   |"KEYONE":"Value One",| &&
   |"KEYTWO": "Value \\\\ two", | &&
   |"KEYTHREE": "Value \\" Three", | &&
   |"KEYFOUR": "ValueFour\\\\" | &&
   |\}|.

   lv_json_string = `{"JUNK":` && lv_json_string && `}`.


CALL TRANSFORMATION id SOURCE XML lv_json_string
          RESULT junk = ls_data.  "


Write: / ls_data-keyone,ls_data-keytwo, ls_data-keythree , ls_data-keyfour.




  ENDMETHOD.

  METHOD json_stru_traverse.
    DATA l_src_json TYPE string.
    DATA: lo_node TYPE REF TO if_sxml_node.
    DATA: lif_element       TYPE REF TO if_sxml_open_element,
          lif_element_close TYPE REF TO if_sxml_close_element,
          lif_value_node    TYPE REF TO if_sxml_value,
          l_val             TYPE string,
          l_attr            TYPE if_sxml_attribute=>attributes,
          l_att_val         TYPE string.
    FIELD-SYMBOLS: <attr> LIKE LINE OF l_attr.


    WRITE: / 'DEMO 2 Traverse any json  document'.

    l_src_json = `{"MATNR":"012345678", "MATKL": "DUMMY", "SOMENODE": "With this value" }`.

    WRITE: / 'Parse as JSON with 3 nodes -> ', l_src_json.


    DATA(reader) = cl_sxml_string_reader=>create( cl_abap_codepage=>convert_to(  l_src_json ) ).


    lo_node = reader->read_next_node( ).   " {
    IF lo_node IS INITIAL.
      EXIT.
    ENDIF.

    DO 3 TIMES.


      lif_element ?= reader->read_next_node( ).
      l_attr =  lif_element->get_attributes( ).
      LOOP AT l_attr ASSIGNING <attr>.
        l_att_val =  <attr>->get_value( ).
        WRITE: / 'Attribute:', l_att_val.
      ENDLOOP.

      lif_value_node ?= reader->read_next_node( ).
      l_val = lif_value_node->get_value( ).
      WRITE: '=>',  l_val.

      lif_element_close ?= reader->read_next_node( ).


    ENDDO.

  ENDMETHOD.

ENDCLASS.

START-OF-SELECTION.
  DATA lo_lcl TYPE REF TO lcl.
  CREATE OBJECT lo_lcl.
  lo_lcl->json_stru_known( ).
  lo_lcl->json_stru_traverse( ).
```

The SAP system is supplied with many example programs.
Search for       `demo*json`

[SAP docu on json parsing](https://help.sap.com/doc/abapdocu_751_index_htm/7.51/en-us/abenabap_json_sxml.htm)

Comment: would you mind adding a minimal working example for OPs problem? You could copy the type definition and json string initialization from my answer.

Comment: Sorry, I meant an example matching OPs question. The code you added just now looks overly complex tbh.

Comment: OK, long story short: If the JSON has only upper case keys there's an easy and performant way to deserialize using `CALL TRANSFORMATION ... SOURCE XML`. Otherwise you do need a lot of boilerplate code that deals with stuff on a much lower level. I'd choose the option with bad performance but readable code if performance was not my main concern. Otherwise unittests with wide coverage might be advisable.

Comment: did you try /ui2/cl_json with lowercase against a local type ?

Comment: Hrm.. Honestly: no.

Comment: Shame because about the only useful thing about /ui2/cl_json is that is has pretty printing internally and does case conversion (amongst other things).  Your posted code actually works. Thanks to the macro FORMAT_NAME in class /ui2/cl_json.  You code have claimed that as a benefit:)